# Inconsistent return address with telnet

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am trying to execute a shellcode in the configuration:

- No VA randomization (set to 0)
- Server is listening on port 9000
- Terminal listening with netcast on port 31337
- Server and attacker are the same (virtual) machine, kali linux 2018.4 32-bit

The shellcode aims to do a shell_reverse_tcp. The payload was generated with the linux/x86/shell_reverse_tcp LPORT=31337 LHOST=127.0.0.1 and shikata_ga_nai encoder.

I found saved EIP and sent the payload with a nop sled, the shellcode and the address which is `\x70\xee\xff\xbf`
Running the server with gdb, I see that the address that arrives is `\x70\xee\xff\xff`

If I put "ABCD" in the address I correctly see the string in hex, but I cannot set the address (which refers to the middle of the nop sled) as it "resets" itself to \xff

Is that a problem due to encoding, or maybe telenet ?

**EDIT**:
It looks like `0xbfxxxxxx` changes to `0xffxxxxxx` when the following character is also `f`. I don't know why. If I change to something else, it does not change the first two characters to `ff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem cam from telnet.

Telnet transmits `\xbf\xff` as `\xff\xff` in the command 
`echo $(python -c 'print "\x90"*300 + "\x77\x77\xff\xbf"') | telnet localhost 7777`

Using netcast solved the issue.